# Beautiful Android Sample open source app

Tags: android, layout, wysiwyg

I'm looking for a nice looking, open source Android app.

The main focus: design in XMLs.
I'd like an app that its design (layouts) is visible in the dev environment - **not** "programmaticaly" built.
A real "What You See Is What You Get" (WYSIWYG)!

I'd really like to learn from such an app!!!

My main problem is that I can't seem to create a nice looking design for my app.
When I use the designer, things just don't add up correctly.
When trying to create a nice title, things get smudged. (Some apps don't even use the title but create a title as part of the content view, like [Google's IO sched](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/)).
When viewing the design on different screen sizes, the buttons run over each other on small screens and have too much space on large screens.

Don't get me wrong. I invested a lot of time to find solutions to each and every problem, but I feel that I could have done things a lot easier and my app could have looked a lot nicer.

I saw some apps, like [Google's IO sched](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/), and they indeed look nice.
The problem is that they do a lot of UI/layout/design calculation "programmaticaly", like the title and the main view. You can't really see the design without running the app. Very hard to develop this way. Too long cycles to get to a nice looking app.

Ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Theres no secret sauce.  It takes hard work and a lot of time working on it

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing, believe me - months of hard work. I just don't understand why it can't be easier. Perhaps the Android platform or dev env isn't mature enough for design?

Comment: Answers to the question: http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/ ; http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/10-open-source-android-apps-which-every-android-developer-must-look-into ; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open_source_Android_applications  WHAT IS THE BEST ONE TO LEARN FROM???

Comment: Question closed without even providing a comment on the reason - come on guys!!!

Comment: Found a great looking Android app, which is also open source. It's written using the right styling mechanism and layout.it's called c:geo. http://cgeo.org/ OR https://github.com/cgeo/c-geo-opensource. Enjoy and thanks to c:geo.

Comment: It seems I'm not the only one. Finally Android released new UI guidelines: http://developer.android.com/design

Answer (score 0):

It takes a lot of time to create a good design. And a lost of practice. I suggest you use demo app in the Android SDK folder on your hard disk. You can also do reverse engineering of the app you like and see how it was made. Of course, this method is not ethical or legal if you use it to copy the app or you produce your own app from the stolen code.

Comment: You want him to reverse engineer an app just to figure out how to lay out UI elements so they don't overlap? :O

Comment: Of course not :). If he likes some layout and he does not know how to make it, then the RI is a good learning step. Don't you agree?!

Comment: It's more than just laying elements. It's the title, the actions, the colors, **the sizes**. A LOT. I can make a very functional app, but it will just not look good enough.

Comment: There are a lot of difficulties in Android UI development. It starts in Eclipse designer that looks different on real devices and even in the emulator. It continues with texts not matching the size of their container and ends in lots of UI tweaks in code (like the IO sched app), causing huge development cycles, because you can't see the result until the app is being run. **There are a lot of other issues!!!**

Comment: I just want to learn from someone who found solutions better than I found. Some app that it's UI is developed with correct methodology, using the WYSIWYG designer, with minimal UI code tweaks, etc.

Comment: I try to answer questions in Stackoverflow so I could help others. I know others struggle with Android UI as well. This posted question is supposed to answer the UI problem by example!!!